# CMake run custom command with mixed shell scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cmake

Let's say we want to run following command in CMake `add_custom_command`:

```
echo "#define FOO \"$(sh tools/foo.sh)\"" > foo.h
```

The *foo.sh* is a script maintained by others so we could not easily change it here.

The problem is, CMake will not evaluate `\"$(sh tools/foo.sh)\"' in`add_costom_command`, instead it just copy them into *foo.h* directly, which is obvious not what we want.

In the generated *build.make* I found something like:

```
echo "#define FOO \"\$$(sh tools/foo.sh)\"" > .../foo.h
```

What're the escape rules for CMake `add_custom_command` `COMMAND`?

How should I write the command in `add_custom_command` `COMMAND`?

Comment: `COMMAND echo "#define FOO \"$(sh tools/foo.sh)\"" > foo.h` ? What have you tried? Did it work? I would split it in two `COMMAND printf "#define FOO" > foo.h COMMAND sh tools/foo.sh >> foo.h` seems more readable.

Comment: @KamilCuk edited

Comment: `What'are the escape rules` read about `VERBATIM`. Did you pass `VERBATIM` to `add_custom_command`? Anyway, the proper way would be to spawn a shell yourself. Like `COMMAND sh -c '"{ echo \"#define FOO\"; sh tools/foo.sh; } > foo.h"`, or if you have to `COMMAND sh -c "echo \"#define FOO \\\"$(sh tools/foo.sh)\\\"\" > foo.h"` but that escaping.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks. Yes I called `add_custom_command` with `VERBATIM`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake syntax is crazy and it's not easy to make this kind of escaping (involves [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake), [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) and [makefile](/questions/tagged/makefile)) right. To work it around I suggest you put the shell command in a separate file (e.g. `helper.sh`) in your project dir and then call it like this --

```
add_custom_command(
  ...
  COMMAND bash ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/helper.sh > foo.h
)
```